# Will Kurn be able to enter StoVoKor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon

In ST:DS9 4x15 "Sons of Mogh," Kurn attempts Klingon ritual suicide so as to enter StoVoKor by dying with honor. By the end of the episode, Worf has his memories erased and he is taken in by a family friend as Rodek, son of Noggra.

As a Klingon, I don't get how Worf was okay doing this. More to the point, how does a Klingon enter StoVoKor? Will he enter as Kurn, or as Rodek? Does changing his entire identity - and that only in a medical way, as there was no Klingon ritual they undertook to change his identity - change who he is when he tries to go to StoVoKor?

How did this ultimately help Kurn with his ultimate concern of entering StoVoKor?

Comment: His soul goes to Sto'Vo'Kor, not his body. Souls are tricky things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kurn's identify was erased and he was reborn as Rodek, son of Noggra. Since Sto'Vo'Kor and Gre'thor are *religious* constructions, there's no good way to tell what will actually happen to his 'soul' after death, even assuming that he has one and that something happens to it.

Certainly Worf (and, crucially, Noggra) believe that what they've done will result in him being able to share the honour of the house of Noggra instead of being stained by the dishonour of the House of Mogh.

Comment: I would think that Kurn/Rodek's ultimate fate would be determined by how he acquits himself as a Klingon moving forward. His identity may have changed, but his character presumably would remain the same, so I think his chances are good.

Comment: @RobJarvis - When Worf joins the house of Martok, it dramatically improves his 'honour', to be associated with their family.